# TSLint error:: Node interpreter path is incorrect. Please check interpreter settings

Tags: angular, webstorm

I am new to Angular. Curious to know whats the error. How to resolve it? I am using web storm IDE.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

This is how I got rid of this warning in Intellij.

Change this:

[image]

to this:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

First of all, it has nothing to do with Angular. It's a tslint issue in your IDE.

It looks like you did not select the node interpreter in your tslint settings. In Webstorm go to Preferences --> Expand Languages & Frameworks --> Expand Typescript --> Select TSLint. If "Enable" is checked, you have to select the node interpretor. This is location of where your node installation. I use NVM, so here are my settings.

[image]

node interpreter : `~/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.0/bin/node`
TSLint package : `~/WebstormProjects/search/node_modules/tslint`

Answer (score 0):

You need to Add `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin` to your `Path` environment variable

1) Search 'environment variables'

2) Click on Environment Variables...

3) Click 'Path', then Edit

4) Click 'New' and add your path to bin, in my case: `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin`