# TSLint error:: Node interpreter path is incorrect

Tags: angular, typescript, webstorm, tslint

I have exactly the same problem as in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45108329/tslint-error-node-interpreter-path-is-incorrect-please-check-interpreter-sett)

I made these settings, but it did not solve my problem 
[image]

What could be the problem?

Comment: Have you tried to clean the project and also updating the dependencies after this change?

Comment: No, do I need to delete the project and install node_modules again?

Comment: settings look correct; did you try specifying other Node.js interpreters there? I'd suggest creating a support ticket, attaching your idea.log (https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085-Locating-IDE-log-files) to it

Comment: @ДмитрийКачуринец I'm not talking about deleting the project, just run update in your package manager, for example npm

Comment: how to update npm ? do you mean npm update or npm install?